# Why does sizeof (void(*)(void)) print 8?

Tags: c, syntax, sizeof, void

I have seen following weird type of syntax on [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof):

```
printf("sizeof(void(*)(void))  = %zu\n", sizeof(void(*)(void)));
```

- What is the meaning of `void(*)(void)`?
- What does it do?
- When and where should i use it?
- Why does `sizeof` it 8?

Comment: It’s a pointer to a function and it’s 8 because on the platform you’re running it pointers seem to be 8 bytes long.

Comment: Question 1: if you don;t know what it is, why'd you write the code? It's not mix-n-match until it compiles somehow, right?

Comment: Question 2: It does not do anything. Nothing does not do anything, it's you who _uses_ them.

Comment: Question 3: What did your C book say?

Comment: Question 4: What did you expect? Any other value? Why?

Comment: For future use: [cdecl](https://cdecl.org/?q=%28void%28*%29%28void%29%29b)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because a function pointer is 8 bytes on that platform.

The expression `void(*)(void)` is a pointer to a function that takes no arguments and has no return value, so that's the type whose size you're asking for.

So, attacking your list:

1. It's a function pointer.
2. It doesn't "do" anything, it's a type. It can be used to hold the address of a function.
3. When you need to store the address of a function.
4. Probably because you're on a 64-bit platform where pointers are 8 bytes.